# Unable to install Python tar.gz package on Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool via Workspace Package

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a Python package which is only available as tar.gz package (arcgis). I want to use it in a Python notebook on Azure Synapse and therefor want to install it on the spark pool. I cannot use the requirements.txt file since private endpoints are setup. So the only way I'm aware of is uploading the file as Workspace package. Then choosing the package in the specific spark pool to apply it there.

The issue is that the library manager of the spark pool recognizes the .tar.gz file as R Package (even though it is a Python package) and therefore processes it with the R library manager.

```
23/09/06 14:48:42 INFO spark.synapse.library-manager.R.custom-tar-path: wasb://prep@*****.blob.core.windows.net/***/libraries/arcgis-2.1.0.3.tar.gz
```

This results in following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/library-manager/bin/lmjob/spark22/libraries/R/PACKAGES'
```

Does anyone has experienced the same? How to overcome this issue?

I don't want to build the arcgis wheel on a Linux server by myself as a workaround.
I'm using Apache Spark version 3.2 with Python 3.8 installed.

Thanks for any tips and hints.

Comment: Check this related to arcgis(GeoAnalytics Engine on Azure Synapse Analytics) 
https://developers.arcgis.com/geoanalytics/install/azure_syn/

Comment: GeoAnalytics is a different Python library (https://pypi.org/project/geoAnalytics/) which exists as wheel. I need the Python library arcgis (https://pypi.org/project/arcgis/).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the corresponding Microsoft documentation where it says .tar.gz files are only supported for R packages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-azure-portal-add-libraries#manage-workspace-packages

So it seems the only way is getting the .whl file somehow.